# Unable to access the element in the frame

Tags: selenium

I am still dipping my toes in selenium , I am SAP guy working on Selenium automation POC. my requirement is to click on the drop down and select a value from the droplist.

I have extensively looked at the previous posts but could not find any answers. I have tried all the suggestions from the post but nothing seems to be working for me.

Please can you help me how to access this drop down value.

HTML code is attached in the pic along with the element that I am trying to access

My selenium code :

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("SMFrame")));
System.out.println("TExt" + driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='file-type']")).getText());
```

Error:

```
error -- > no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='file-type']"}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJjDR.png)

Comment: Appreciate your help , as I have a demo to prepare and I have no leads till now

Comment: Take a look at Katalon recorder browser extension.You can click on what you need and it will give you an Xpath to it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are correctly getting into the iframe

Right now you are selecting a div above the actual dropdown element (the select-dropdown tag). You may want to try changing your xpath to search for the  tag like so:

```
//div[@class='file-dropdown']/select-dropdown
```

Also you should be creating a dropdown object like this. Then calling a method on it to select the dropdown option you are looking for:

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='file-dropdown']/select-dropdown");  
System.out.println(dropdown.selectByVisibleText("text that you are looking for in the options"));
```

This is a good explanation of how to do it: https://www.javatpoint.com/selenium-webdriver-handling-drop-downs

Comment: I have gone through this but in my case there is a frame that is invoked and I am not able to access the element in the frame. I am getting the error invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[@class='file-dropdown'. I am stuck at a place where I am not able to call the element in the frame. I hope I was able to explain the error better.

Comment: are there more than that one iframe on the page?

Comment: I have tried the way you suggested , my code looks like this now 

  driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("SMFrame")));

 
     Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='file-dropdown']/select-dropdown")));  
    // System.out.println(dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Suppliers"));
     System.out.println("TExt");

i am getting error  " no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='file-dropdown']/select-dropdown"}"

Comment: The HTML code is is attached as picture for better understanding of how the code is  structured and elements are arranged.

Comment: hmm it seems like the problem may be that you arent selecting the iframe properly. Have you tried changing By.name("SMFrame) to by id. I dont see why nbot to use id value instead since it is unique.

Comment: I did , but the error still exists

   driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("SMFrame")));

 
     Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='file-dropdown']/select-dropdown")));  
    // System.out.println(dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Suppliers"));
     System.out.println("TExt");


 no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='file-dropdown']/select-dropdown"}

Comment: you may be able to play with the following to select the iframe you need. Start with driver.switchTo().frame(0)

Comment: Could help if you added a fragment of the html you are working with that contains the iframe. Then it would be easier to write up some scripts to test it.

Comment: <iframe onload="if(typeof resizeIframe === 'function') resizeIframe('SMFrame', 0); return false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="750" id="SMFrame" src="https://s1.ariba.com/SM/rest/angular2.html?v=436519/#/supplier-admin?realm=IBM-S-T&amp;token=5128f12e-1c33-4772-be6b-f34ee48bef02" name="SMFrame" style="display: block; width: 1280px; height: 750px;" xpath="1">
Ariba
</iframe>

Comment: This is the fragment George

Comment: I was able to resolve this with the below command

filetype = //div[@class='file-type']/following-sibling::div/select-dropdown/div[@class='select']

Comment: Glad to hear it! Yeah it's pretty common to write up incorrect xpath to reach an element. I often get stuck on that myself when scripting for my frameworks.